# which design is better for a client/server project with lots of data sharing

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, design-patterns

Let's say we have a project that will handle lots of data (employees, schedules, calendars....and lots more). Client is Windows App, Server side is WCF. Database is MS SQL Server. I am confused regarding which approach to use. I read few articles and blogs they all seem nice but I am confused. I don't want to start with one approach and then regret not choosing the other. The project will have around 30-35 different object types. A lot of Data retrieving to populate different reports...etc

**Approach 1:**

```
// classes that hold data

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    .....
}

public class Assignment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    .....
}
.....
```

Then Helper classes to deal with data saving and retrieving:

```
public static class Employees
{
    public static int Save(Employee emp)
    {
        // save the employee
    }

    public static Employee Get(int empId)
    {
        // return the ugly employee
    }
    .....
}

public static class Assignments
{
    public static int Save(Assignment ass)
    {
        // save the Assignment
    }
    .....
}
```

FYI, The object classes like Employees and Assignment will be in a separate Assembly to be shared between Sever and Client.
Anyway, with this approach I will have a cleaner objects. The Helper classes will do most of the job.

**Approach 2:**

```
// classes that hold data and methods for saving and retrieving

public class Employee
{
    // constructors
    public Employee()
    {
        // Construct a new Employee
    }
    public Employee(int Id)
    {
        // Construct a new Employee and fills the data from db
    }

     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
    .....

    public int Save()
    {
        // save the Employee
    }
    .....
}

public class Assignment
{
    // constructors
    public Assignment()
    {
        // Construct a new assignment
    }
    public Assignment(int Id)
    {
        // Construct a new assignment and fills the data from db
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    .....

    public int Save()
    {
        // save the Assignment
    }
    .....
}
.....
```

With this approach, Each object will do its own job.. Data still can be transferred from WCF to client easily since WCF will only share properties.

**Approach 3:**

Using Entity Framework.. beside the fact that I never worked with it (which is nice since I have to learn something new) I will need to create POCOs to transfer data between client and WCF..

Now, Which is better? more options?

Comment: A good question, but perhaps a better fit for Programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using Entity Framework + Repository pattern. This way your entities are simple objects without any logic in them. All retrieve-save logic stays in repository. I have some successful experience with using generic repository, which is typed with entity, something similar is described [here](http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-ef4-generic-repository-and-unit-of-work-prototype/) (generic repository part of the article). This way you write repository code only once and you can reuse it for all entities you have. E.g.:

```
interface IRepositry<T>
{
 T GetById(long id);
 bool Save(T entity);
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> {...}

var repository = new Repository<MyEntity>();
var myEntity = repository.GetById(1);
var repository2 = new Repository<MySecondEntity>();
var mySecondEntity = repository.GetById(1);
```

Whenever an entity needs some very specific operation, you can add this operation to a concrete typed implementation of IRepository:

```
interface IMySuperRepositry : IRepository<MySuperEntity>
{
   MySuperEntity GetBySuperProperty(SuperProperty superProperty);
}

public class MySuperEntityRepository : Repository, IMySuperRepository
{...}
```

To create repositories it is nice to use a factory, which is based for example on configuration file. This way you can switch implementation of repositories, e.g. for unit testing, when you do not want to use repository that really accesses DB:

```
public class RepositoryFactory
{
  IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>()
{
  if (config == production) 
     return new Repository<T>(); // this is implemented with DB access through EF
  if (config == test)
     return new TestRepository<T>(); // this is implemented with test values without DB access
}
}
```

}
}

You can add validation rules for saving and further elaborate on this. EF also lets you add some simple methods or properties to generated entities, because all of them are partial classes.

Furthermore using POCOs or STEs (see later) it is possible to have EDMX DB model in one project, and all your entities in another project and thus distribute this DLL to client (which will contain ONLY your entities). As I understood, that's what you also want to achieve.

Also seriously consider using [Self tracking entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407090.aspx) (and not just POCOs). In my opinion they are great for usage with WCF. When you get an entity from DB and pass it to the client, client changes it and gives it back, you need to know, if entity was changed and what was changed. STEs handle all this work for you and are designed specifically for WCF. You get entity from client, say ApplyChanges and Save, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Having peristence logic in object itself is always a bad idea.

I would use first aproach. It looks like [Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). This way, you can easily debug peristing of data, because it will be clearly separated from rest of the logic of the object.

Answer (score 0):

What about implementing the Save as an extension method? That way your classes are clean as in the first option, but the methods can be called on the object as in the second option.

```
public static class Employee
{
    public static int Save(this Employee emp)
    {
        // save the employee
    }

    public static Employee Get(int empId)
    {
        // return the ugly employee
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're over thinking this. trying to apply technologies and patterns "just because" or "that's what they say" only makes the solution complicated. The key is designing the application so that it can easily adapt to change. that's probably an ambiguous answer, but it's what it all comes down to. how much effort is required to maintain and/or modify the code base.

currently it sounds like the patterns and practices are the end result, instead of a means to an end.

Comment: I intend to over think it.. Over thinking is not usually bad. It leads to learning new things.. Any way your point about the effort required to maintain the code is the main point.. but still trying something new is a point as well..

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is a great tool but is not necessarily the best choice in all cases. It will depend on how much you expect to read/write from the database vs how much you expect to read/write to your WCF services. Perhaps someone better-versed in the wonderful world of EF will be able to help you. To speak from experience, I have used LINQ-TO-SQL in an application that features WCF service endpoints and had no issues (and in fact came to LOVE Linq-To-Sql as an ORM).

Having that said, if you decide that EF is not the right choice for you, it looks like you're on the right track with **Approach 1**. However, I would recommend implementing a [Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Access_Object) [Access](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/introduction/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs) [Layer](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/.net-application-architecture-the-data-access-layer/). That is, implement a `Persist` method in your business classes that then calls methods in a separate DAO (Data Access Object, or a class used to persist data from a business object) to actually save it to your database.

A sample implementation might look like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public void Persist()
    {
        EmployeeDAO.Persist(this);
    }
}

public class Assignment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public void Persist()
    {
        AssignmentDAO.Persist(this);
    }
}

public static class EmployeeDAO
{
    public static int Persist(Employee emp)
    {
        // insert if new, else update
    }

    public static Employee Get(int empId)
    {
        // return the ugly employee
    }
    .....
}

public static class AssignmentDAO
{
    public static int Persist(Assignment ass)
    {
        // insert if new, else update
    }
    .....
}
```

The benefit to a pattern like this is that you get to keep your business classes clean, your data-access logic separate, while still giving the objects the easy syntax of being able to write `new Employee(...).Persist();` in your code.

If you really want to go nuts, you could even consider implementing interfaces on your *Persistable* classes, and have your DAO(s) accept those `IPersistable` instances as arguments.

Comment: Your approach is nice, Looks like "Approach 1" and "Approach 2" got married and had your Approach as a baby.. I will wait for more options and opinions..